# The number of passengers in the airplane

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In an airplane, the passengers are asked which languages they can speak. 37 passengers can speak German. 53 can speak English. 65 can speak French. 15 can speak English and German. 15 can speak German and French. 25 can speak English and French, and 5 can speak English, French and German. Find the following.

$a)$ the number of passengers in the airplane

$b)$ the number of passengres who can speak only two languages

$c)$ the number of passengers who cannot speak French or English

My answers is:
$a) 110,$ $b) 15,$ $c) 12$

I do not know a precise answer, please confirm me if my answer is correct, if not help to solve this example

Comment: I get 40 for b) - if you add together the numbers who can speak 2 of the languages, then each of those figures includes the 5 who speak all 3 - I drew a venn diagram

Comment: if 25 can speak english and french, then 5 of those also speak German - so that itself must add 20 who speak exactly 2 (of the listes) languages - so I'm convinced 15 is wrong for b

Comment: Can you please not draw, Venn diagram to see how

Comment: according to what you think, my answer are correct

Comment: why can't I draw a venn diagram?  OK I ripped it up - c is Geman speakers - (German/English) - ((German/French) + (all 3)) = 12

Comment: I make concur with a) and c) but b) seems wrong.

Comment: for you only b) is incorrect

Comment: From what I can understand from you is this: a) ok=110, b) 40 c)12. Is that what you think

Comment: yes I make it 110,40,12